# Como mandar el valor de una variable extraida de la base de datos a un modal?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy intentando hacer un formulario que me permita agregar los empleados que recibieron X capacitación en un listado (aun no logro llegar a esa parte) lo que he hecho es tener 1 combobox para mostrar los cargos que hay por área de trabajo eso funciona perfectamente ahora donde estoy estancado es en que quiero que cargar que personal pertenece al cargo que escogí en el combobox cargando esos datos en un modal, probé usando variables de sesión y sirve pero cuando escojo el cargo no pasa nada tengo que actualizar para que tome ese dato y lo que yo busco es que funcione una vez que elija el cargo muestre los datos mientras no haya nada pues claro no habrá nada lo que tengo es esto:

FORMULARIO

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <form   method="POST">
            <h1>FORMACIÓN DEL PERSONAL</h1>

            <div class="contentform">
                <div class="leftcontact">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>Tipo de cargo</p>
                        <select id="cargo" name="cargo" required>
                        </select>   
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>Capacitacion</p>
                        <input type="text" name="capa">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="rightcontact">

                    <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal">
                        Agregar personal
                    </button>   
                </div>      
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="bottom">Guardar</button>    
        </form> 

        <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
        <script src="js/carga.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <?php include "zius.php";?>
```

CARGO

```
<?php
function aer(){
  include 'config/conexion.php';
  $boo = 'SELECT * FROM cargo
          order by Cargo asc';
  $result = $cone->query($boo);
  $listas = '<option value="0">Elige una opción</option>';
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $listas .= "<option value='$row[Id_cargo]'>$row[Cargo]</option>";
  }
  return $listas;
}

echo aer();
```

LISTA

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'cargo.php',
  })
  .done(function(listas_ar){
    $('#cargo').html(listas_ar)
  })
  .fail(function(){
    alert('Hubo un error al cargar los cargos')
  })
})
```

MODAL ZIUS

```
<?php 

  include "conexion/db.php";
  $clu= $_SESSION['Id_cargo'];
  $id= $clu;
  $sql = "SELECT a.Id_foto, a.Nombre_em, b.Id_cargo, b.Cargo
          FROM personal as a 
          INNER JOIN cargo b on b.Id_cargo = a.Id_cargo
          where b.Id_cargo ='$id'";
  $resul = $cone->query($sql);

?>
<div class="modal fade" id="miModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><br>
                </button>

                <h4><center>Empleados</center></h4>

                <div><br ><br > 
                    <input type="text" id="buscar" class="buscar" style="width: 100%; margin-left: -90% !important;" placeholder="Buscar...">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table id="tabla" border="1" class='tabla_datos'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr id="titulo">
                            <th><center>Nº Foto</center></th>
                            <th><center>Nombre</center></th>
                            <th><center>Cargo</center></th>
                            <th>Comando</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php while ($row = $resul->fetch_assoc()) 
                        {?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php $codigo = $row['Id_foto']; echo $codigo; ?></td>
                                <td><?php $equi = $row['Nombre_em']; echo $equi; ?></td>
                                <td><?php $secc = $row['Cargo']; echo $secc; ?></td>
                                <td><button class="bor" onclick="agregarEquipo('<?php echo $codigo;?>', '<?php echo $equi;?>')" data-dismiss="modal">Agregar</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php }?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/buscar.js"></script>
```

en el archivo cargo es la consulta de la tabla y  lista.js que me permitirá cargar los datos de la consulta en el combobox, espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Necesitas obtener el valor que seleccionaste del `select` con id `cargo`?

Comment: Exacto, que tras elegir el cargo tome ese id lo mande al modal y que me cargue los empleados que tiene ese cargo e igual si elijo otro lo mismo

Comment: Pues haz otro ajax pero con `change` del select cargo y mandas por `$_POST['id_cargo']` y haces la consulta con ese valor y abres el modal con `.modal('show');`.

Comment: Podrías explicarme mejor la ultima parte no la comprendo mucho no tengo mucha experiencia con el modal

Comment: Vale deja te pongo una respuesta con ejemplo..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo el ejemplo de como usarías el ajax para mandar el id de cargo a tu archivo donde tienes el modal, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
$('#cargo').on('change', function(){

  console.log($(this).val());
  let cargo = $(this).val();
  
  $.ajax({
        url: 'zius.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: '',
        data: {id_cargo: cargo}
      })
      .done(function(response) {
//ya que mandaste tu id y ejecutada tu consulta muestras el modal
$('$exampleModal').modal('show');

});

});

$('#clic').click(function(){

    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
  
    <select id="cargo">
    <option value="">Selecciona...</option>
    <option value="Director">Director</option>
    <option value="Secretaria">Secretaria</option>
    <option value="Enlace">Enlace</option>
    
    </select>

<button id="clic">Oprime para ver el modal</button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <span id="text">En vez de esto sería tu tabla</span>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias probare

Comment: Amigo estuve probando varias formas pero nunca puedo recibir el id de cargo en el modal y utilizo el  $id = $_POST['Id_cargo']; y nunca puedo recibirlo